# Namespace prefix “app” cannot find declaration

Tags: android, android-cardview

While I try to add [wenchaojiang AndroidSwipeableCardStack](https://github.com/wenchaojiang/AndroidSwipeableCardStack) library to my project. While I succeed to add this library but got an error in the following case.
In main Activity layout, I required adding the,

```
<com.wenchao.cardstack.CardStack
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
   />
```

Also I need to add the following with this

```
    app:card_enable_loop="false"
    app:card_enable_rotation="true"
    app:card_gravity="top"
    app:card_margin="20dp"
    app:card_stack_size="4"
```

I got error as `Decleration not found` or `error: attribute 'business.contacts.cardwithlib:card_enable_loop' not found.`

I try many solutions like,

Include card `'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'` , add auto-generating  `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and Open their project and work fine for me in that project

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are no including the Android's `CardView` but what it looks like a 3rd party library.

```
com.wenchao.cardstack.CardStack
```

Is this intentional? If so, maybe this component doesn't extend the `CardView` element, those specific style attributes might not be available.

Comment: The sample project they provide working fine with this attribute , but while I try to create my own get the error

Comment: Can you compare your project dependencies with the `sample` ?

Comment: Project dependencies are exactly same and its work while adding aar file, not with gradle lib.

Comment: I don't have enough context to help you out more, but I would suggest you try and use the Framework's own `CardView` with those attributes.